# Modify custom module's setting.yml without reinstalling

Tags: 8, configuration

I have made a simple custom module in Drupal 8, in which I use a settings file (config/install/my_module.settings.yml)

I have one entry, let's say

```
module:
  key: 'qsdqsd'
```

So when I install the module, I can use this entry in my controllers. 
But if I need to modify anything in this file (adding an entry, for instance...) I can't use it in my controllers (config->get(module.new_entry) returns NULL) unless I uninstall then reinstall the module.

`drush cache-rebuild` did not help neither.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to handle this would be to write a hook_update_n() function and write the code out that would add those new config keys.

Then you would run `drush updb` and it would be added to the website.

The other answer is correct as well. I use both together and we can track everything in GIT from dev > stage > prod in case there are changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the module [config_sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_sync), there you can update the site's configuration from your custom module.

afaik there is no official way to update configuration from an updated module.

Comment: The "official" way to handle data schema changes in an updated module is to use a hook_update_N().